# Jquery each event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to validate a login form. I am taking children of a div and iterating to all input elements. Everything working fine.But when focus moves on to password field and if i remove all values of username it doesn't give required error. My code

```
<div class="login-contents">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control login-check" id="login-name" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control login-check" id="login-pass" placeholder="Password">
</div>

<div id="login-error" class="alert alert-danger"></div>
```

And Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login-form").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#login-error").removeClass("alert alert-danger");
    var name_min_length = 2;
    var pass_min_length = 5 ;

$(".login-contents").children('input').each(function(){
    $(".login-check").keyup(function(){
        var name = $("#login-name").val();
        name = jQuery.trim(name).length;
        var name_length = length_check(name,name_min_length);
        console.log(name_length);

        var pass = $("#login-pass").val();
        pass = jQuery.trim(pass).length;
        var pass_length = length_check(pass,pass_min_length);
        console.log(pass_length);
    });
});


function length_check(value,number){
    if (value < number) {
        $("#login-error").addClass("alert alert-danger").html("Minimum length");
    }
    else{
        $("#login-error").removeClass("alert alert-danger").html("");
        return true ;
    }
}
});
```

Any suggestion where i am doing wrong

Comment: You set the disabled prop to true. Disabled forms and input elements do not get validated.

Comment: FYI: You don't need to loop through inputs in this case!

Comment: If all required fields are as desired and i will remove prop disable.

Let me check @Dhaval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems right you just need to change your logic like following with lesser code:

No need of `.each` loop in this case you can access `this` (current element where keyup fired) in your code by using class selector `.login-check`!

```
$(".login-check").keyup(function(){
        var name = $(this).val();
        var elemType = $(this).attr('name')
        name = jQuery.trim(name).length;
        var length = length_check(name, elemType == 'name' ? name_min_length : pass_min_length); // if element is name length will be 2 otherwise 5 for pass
        console.log(length);
    });
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2z72rjf5/)

Answer (score 0):

First thing to know is, you don't have to loop through input to register events, class selector will do that for you and you can handle length_check in a single function. Try this

```
//$(".login-contents").children('input').each(function(){
$(".login-check").keyup(function(){
    var value = trim(this.value).length;
    if(this.name == "name"){
      var result = length_check(value,name_min_length); 
    } else(this.name == "pass") {
       var result = length_check(value,pass_min_length); 
    }
    console.log(result);

});
//});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using the same div and code for showing error both for name and password field. And password field is checked last, so no matter what value has name field it will always show no error. Here is working code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#login-form").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#login-error").removeClass("alert alert-danger");
  var name_min_length = 2;
  var pass_min_length = 5;

  $(".login-contents").children('input').each(function() {
    $(".login-check").keyup(function() {
      var name = $("#login-name").val();
      name = jQuery.trim(name).length;
      var name_length_ok = length_check(name, name_min_length);
      console.log(name_length_ok);

      var pass = $("#login-pass").val();
      pass = jQuery.trim(pass).length;
      var pass_length_ok = length_check(pass, pass_min_length);
      console.log(pass_length_ok);
      
      toggle_error(!name_length_ok || !pass_length_ok);
    });
  });

  function length_check(value, number) {
    return value >= number;
  }
  
  function toggle_error(toggle) {
    if (toggle) {
      $("#login-error").addClass("alert alert-danger").html("Minimum length");
    } else {
      $("#login-error").removeClass("alert alert-danger").html("");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login-contents">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control login-check" id="login-name" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control login-check" id="login-pass" placeholder="Password">
</div>

<div id="login-error" class="alert alert-danger"></div>
```